# Converting twitter archive unicode escape

Tags: unix, twitter, unicode, utf-8

I have a twitter archive containing about 60 000 tweets, mostly in french. 
In these, accented characters are represented using U-escaped hexadecimal. E.g the word "animée" is represented as "anim\u00E9e". 
Now, I want to convert this to UTF-8. The good news is, there's a unix utility for that, called ascii2uni.

The bad news is that that apparently anything that can be interpreted as an hex digit will be interpreted as such. Therefore instead of "animée", I end up with this nonsense : "animພ"

So how can I convert those tweets to UTF-8 in a way that doesn't mangle it like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ascii2uni` program’s default format does not work well. But fortunately, you can define your own custom format.

```
echo 'aim\u00E9e \uD852\uDF62 bbb' | ascii2uni -Z '\u%04X'
```

The Chinese character is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Examples.

Comment: I tried your first solution and got an error message from iconv "conversion from Java is not supported".

Second solution seems to work. I'll try it and see if there's any error.

Comment: It seems to be working. I had tried to use a regex with a similar assumption but I couldn't make it work, thanks.

Comment: I still get a bunch of errors like this one : 
Unicode surrogate U+D83D is illegal in UTF-8 at -e line 5, <> line 72863.
Unicode surrogate U+DC80 is illegal in UTF-8 at -e line 5, <> line 72863. 
I think they're due either to chinese character or emoji.